# Place divs beside each other in a layout to fill free space

Tags: jquery, css, html

According to the picture I can place divs beside each other using `float` but how can I make them fill the free space?

[image: Layout]

Comment: DUPLICATE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean free space?

Comment: did you try setting the margin & padding to 0?

Comment: @DevlshOne It's not a DUPLICATE !!!

Comment: @Zim3r Yes, it absolutely is. If you read that post you will find the answer to your question.

Comment: @Ali.NET Please take a look at the picture, I want section one to become something like section two.

Comment: @DevlshOne It says: Make a div fill the remaining screen space I don't want to do that! I want divs to be near each other.

Comment: Yes but I can't understand what is the solution exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use containers for each div e.g:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="big"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jt3Az/3/

Answer (score 1):

You make a container for each column and just float them all.

(I added a class of `small` and `big` for size differences.)

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="box small">
    </div>
    <div class="box big">
    </div>
    <div class="box small">
    </div>
    <div class="box big">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <div class="box big">
    </div>
    <div class="box small">
    </div>
    <div class="box big">
    </div>
    <div class="box small">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="c">
    <div class="box small">
    </div>
    <div class="box big">
    </div>
    <div class="box small">
    </div>
    <div class="box big">
    </div>
</div>
```

The css behind this:

```
#a,#b,#c {
    width:50px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}

.box {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Check it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/pvKhQ/